# Zeros in Experiment Analysis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, experiment-design

I am analyzing data of an experiment close to the ultimatum game.
Participant A makes a decision x or y, and then Participant B can decide  whether to punish Participant A. Participant B can choose freely to punish between 0 and 100 cents. I want to test whether Punishment is associated with A's choice. Therefore, I have two hypotheses:

H1: participants in group B punish more often when A chooses y.

For this I constructed a binary variable if people in B punished at all or not. Chi squared test shows no effect.
So far so good. Now H2.

H2: Participants in group B punish more severely when A chooses y.

Only a quarter punished at all, so there are a lot of zeros. Do I exclude the zeros when testing Hypothesis 2? Or is just an MWU test sufficient?

Comment: You would include 0s as 0 punishment in H2, they are not nested hypotheses as stated. It would be different if you reframed H2 conditionally as "*of punishments invoked*, participants in group B punish more severely when A chooses y"

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that too. But besides the formulation of the hypothesis, which way is the proper one to go? Including 0s gives no significant results in MWU and t-test (which is probably invalid). Excluding 0s gives a non significant MWU and a t-test with p=0.1022. The mean of x is 53 and of y is 35. The CI reaches from -3 to 38. This is a trend in the hypothezised direction, but very unprecise probably due to small N (df=28). Im just wondering what to make of that, and if its worth the effort to further investigate (under time constraints) how it behaves with other covariates. Sugg.s?

Comment: Like I said, the hypothesis is a scientific question. I underscored the subtlety of the language here. If you keep H2 as stated, you include the zeros.